# Comparing hash from db (login)

Tags: node.js, bcrypt

How can I compare hash from my db to the users login password? I am using **bcrypt**

story: Login: password plain then encrypt then compare encrypted to encrypted in db

```
exports.Authenticate= async function (data){
    try {
        return bcrypt.compare(data.Password, hash, function(err, result) {
            let sql = 'SELECT * FROM "'+config.MASUSER+'"."Users" WHERE "Email"= $1 AND "Password"= $2 AND "Status"=$3';
                console.log(result)
                return pool.query(sql, [data.Email, data.Password, data.Status])
                .then((res) => { return res;})
                .catch((err) => { return console.error('---Error executing query---\n', err.stack) });
            });
    } catch(err) { return console.error(err); } 
}
```

UPDATE

```
exports.Authenticate = async function(data) {
  try {
    const result = await pool.query(`SELECT "password" FROM ${config.MASUSER}.Users WHERE "Email" = $1 AND "Status" = $2`, [data.Email, data.Status])

    return !result.length ? false : await bcrypt.compare(data.Password, result[0].password)
  } catch (err) {
    return false
  }
}
```

issue, I can login using the hash code from db but not the plain password that the users registered and login

Answer (score 0):

1. Hash the incoming password (with whatever library you are using)
2. Retrieve hashed password from DB.
3. Simply treat the two hashes as strings and compare them with `===`.

Comment: Hi Goodday! I really appreciate your answer, but can you give me a example?

Comment: Hash the incoming password? bcrypt is salted the hash won't be the same

Comment: @LawrenceCherone Then he used the wrong hash function/method. You should never add salt to a hashed password. Because as illustrated there, there is no way to compare it.

Comment: hey guys, can you please help me about this?

Answer (score 0):

1. Select user, not including password in check.
2. Compare input password with hash

Example:

Note because you only want boolean returned from the function, you shouldn't return console.log (which is undefined) if it throws, also as it's an async function you can just await instead of using all the them callbacks.

```js
exports.Authenticate = async function(data) {
  try {
    const result = await pool.query(`
      SELECT password 
      FROM ${config.MASUSER}.Users 
      WHERE "Email" = $1 AND "Status" = $2
    `, [data.Email, data.Status])

    return !result.length ? false : await bcrypt.compare(data.Password, result[0].password)
  } catch (err) {
    return false
  }
}
```

You need to call like `await Authenticate()` still

Comment: I tried this but it always the result not equal

Comment: check data in db, do some debugging on `result` to see if it returned anything, and that password is a bcrypt hash.

Comment: I cant login using the plain password

Comment: I can only login using the hash code saved in the db, not the plain password entered by the user

Comment: did you copy the sql change from my answer? it would help if you added your updated code to your question